# Advanced circle showing percentage

Tags: jquery, html, css

How is it possible to make a circle showing a specific percentage? See http://humblebee.se/this-is-humblebee/emil/.

I see [this](http://bit.ly/1b5WbU5) answer from another question, but I think that it is very hard coded. I want to set the percentage from a html-data attribute for fast development.

Maybe it's easier with jQuery?

Comment: Kindly modify the question as to put a specific problem with any piece of code. Refer to the link: http://stackoverflow.com/help to get an idea what type of questions are expected and encouraged. Thanks.

Comment: you can use js plugins like http://www.chartjs.org/docs/

Comment: Or you can have a look at this plugin: [easy-pie-chart](http://rendro.github.io/easy-pie-chart/). This plugin is also used in bootstrap themes templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to download and install pie chart js library,

and add script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.chart').easyPieChart({
        //your configuration goes here
    });
});
</script>
```

or like other [DEMO](http://codepen.io/genievn/pen/iaKdz)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the answer you provided, actually you can see that the only parameter that you have to play around with is:

```
-webkit-transform:rotate(-55deg);
```

The only thing wrong with the sample is, that it uses IDs only, you should mix using classes and unique IDs for your containers.

If you use JQuery, then you could read the value of the inner div and adapt the value accordingly, where 100% = 360 degrees, so 3.6 degrees per percentage.